# A Solver for 2D bin packing for Large number of Bins (java | Gurobi)

Tags: java, 2d, bin-packing, gurobi

I am looking for a Solver to solve a 2D bin packing problem.
I saw several post, suggesting "Binary Tree Algorithm", but I have around 200,000 of bins, 
So I am not sure if the algorithm is Scalable or not.

I was thinking about Gurobi. But I dont know how to model the problem in Gurobi.
Is any one aware of any available model that I can use?
Or Is there any java code available, that can give me an "close to exact" solution, considering the fact that it is NP hard?

Thanks

/Mina

Answer (score 1):

You could check out the JBoss solution:  http://www.optaplanner.org/

Looks like this guy has given it a try:  https://github.com/MichaelGoff/bin-packing